# Is there a way to prevent the gridview from scrolling to its top position when its adapter's data is changed?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-asynctask, scrollview

after loading more data the grid view back to top, I want to make it keep scrolling from the last item after loading.
I tried to use `onScrollStateChanged`, and make it loading in `state == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL`, but I faced the same problem.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<productDetails> AProducts) {
        final ArrayList<productDetails> products = AProducts;
        super.onPostExecute(products);

        productAdapter = new productAdapter(category.this, productDetailsArr);
        gridView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        if (products != null) {
            gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                        // End has been reached
                        limit = Integer.parseInt(((productDetails) (products.get(products.size() - 1))).getProductID());
                        // limit = Integer.parseInt(products.get(3).get(products.get(3).size() - 1));


                        if (flimit != limit) {
                            flimit = limit; //to stop using last element in fatching last products more than one time.
                            if (UtilityClass.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {

                                                                    new getProductsTask().execute(category);


                            } else {
                                Intent internet = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NointernetConnection.class);
                                startActivity(internet);
                                finish();

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("FLimit", ">>" + "END");
                        }

                    } else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    }

                }

            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to create a new object of your adapter class (productAdapter) every time in onPostExecute method and set adapter to gridview every time when data change or new response of your network call .This causes of scrolling gridview to top position.Instead you can create a setter method in your adapter class.

```
ArrayList <productDetails> productDetailsArr;

 public void setProductDetailsArr(ArrayList<productDetails> productDetailsArr) {
            this.productDetailsArr = productDetailsArr;
        }
```

and in onPostExecute method write down the following code to check if adaper is null or not.If null then only you have to create a new instance.Otherwise you only have to provide a new dataset and just call notifyDataSetChanged().

```
 if(productAdapter == null)
 {
    productAdapter = new productAdapter(category.this, productDetailsArr);
    gridView.setAdapter(productAdapter);

 }else{

     productAdapter.setProductDetailsArr(productDetailsArr);
     productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved much of my time.